# Calling .querySelector() method using call with a context different than the document?

Tags: javascript, dom

In JS, you can call `querySelector` within any DOM element because it has the method in its Element prototype, and it will take effect only in that context, like this:

```
const node = document.getElementById('test-node')
node.querySelector('.example')
```

and it will work fine, but what I wanted to do is call the method after having it passed with a variable using `.call()`, here is what I wanted to do:

```
const querySelector = document.querySelector
querySelector.call(node, '.example')
```

unfortunately this will throw a `TypeError: Illegal invocation` exception, how can I make it work?

Comment: Why not just call `node.querySelector()` directly?? If the value of `node` is a reference to a DOM element, that'll work. If it's *not* a reference to a DOM element, then calling `.querySelector()` with that value as `this` doesn't make sense anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, at least in Chrome, `document` has a different `querySelector` than elements do.

Instead, you can call `Element`'s `querySelector` directly:

```
Element.prototype.querySelector.call(node, 'p')
```